# Can I use Ninject to inject dependencies into attributes rather than using the service locator pattern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, anti-patterns, service-locator

I'm using feature flags to selectively enable/disable certain aspects of my MVC4 web application in different environments. I have an interface named `IConfiguration` with a `IsEnabled(FeatureFlag)` method that provides access to these flags.

To this end, I want to disable certain MVC action methods when the feature they relate to is turned off. I have an attribute named `FeatureAttribute` defined like this:

```
// Usage: [Feature(FeatureFlag.I18N)]
public class FeatureAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute {
    private IConfiguration _config;
    private FeatureFlag _feature;

    public FeatureAttribute(FeatureFlag feature) {
        _config = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IConfiguration>();
        _feature = feature;
    }
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                                           MethodInfo methodInfo) {
        return _config.IsEnabled(_feature);
    }
}
```

This works, [but using `DependencyResolver` to get an instance of `IConfiguration` smells funny](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). Is there any way I can redesign my code to avoid the Service Locator pattern?

I initially thought of using [filter injection](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Dependency-injection-for-filters), but `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` is not actually a filter, so it doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes are created by the .NET Framework. So you can't do Constructor injection. The only two ways to inject into Attributes is to do PropertyInjection or ServiceLocation.

PropertyInjection can be done like this:

1. Add a `IPlanningStrategy` that does the scanning  with reflection for your attribute (or `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`). Return immediatly if not a controller.
2. Foreach method that has this attribute add a `IDirective` that contains a reference to the `MethodInfo`
3. Add A `IActivationStrategy` that injects the attribute using `kernel.Inject(attribute)`.

Best you have a look at the `PropertyInjection` implementation of Ninject it works exactly like this. It just needs some changes to do what you want.